# Java HTTP/HTTPS post from app 1 to app 2 in different server

Tags: java, http, http-post

I have to develop a java application which has to do a http post to a different application. Both the application does not have a JSP page as a front end. (Http POST from servlet to servlet).

When I was exploring options for this I managed to find

**response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/appname/servletname?var1=&var2=?...);**

But this is based on http get. How do I do the same using HTTP post?

Thanks
Arun Kumar

Comment: Take a look at Apache HttpComponents. It should be pretty helpful - http://hc.apache.org/.

Answer (score 2):

The code you found is for redirecting an incoming request to another location. The client ends up sending a new request to the new URL. This is not what you want.

You can make an HTTP request using the class `java.net.URL`. You can then get an OutputStream and write your POST data in the body of the request. You will have to encode all your data values with java.net.URLEncoder.

I think there is a library in Apache commons that makes this easier.